# Merge data frame on either of the 2 columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames. One data frame with one column and second data frame with two columns. I need to merge first data frame with either column of the second data frame and returns the values. After merging the values,the order of the first column should be same as the input.
Please find the sample input below

```
first_column = c("ENSG00000165588","ENSG00000213551")
df1 = data.frame(first_column)
first_column = c("ENSG00000142192", "ENSG00000140575", "ENSG00000165588", "ENSG00000165588", "ENSG00000213551", "ENSG00000213551","ENSG00000197153")
second_column = c("ENSG00000165588", "ENSG00000165588", "ENSG00000186908", "ENSG00000135446", "ENSG00000273983", "ENSG00000274267","ENSG00000213551")
df2 = data.frame(first_column,second_column)
```

Please find the output below.

```
first_column = c("ENSG00000165588","ENSG00000165588","ENSG00000165588","ENSG00000165588","ENSG00000213551","ENSG00000213551","ENSG00000213551")
second_column = c("ENSG00000142192","ENSG00000140575","ENSG00000186908","ENSG00000135446","ENSG00000273983","ENSG00000274267","ENSG00000197153")
output = data.frame(first_column,second_column)
```

Comment: what would happen to rows where `second_column == ENSG00000165588` and `first_column == ENSG00000213551` ? In this case you have a situation where both columns are 'keys'.

Comment: @Wimpel,  I dont have the data what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this?

```
library(data.table)
# set your data to data.table format
setDT(df1); setDT(df2)
# joins
df2[df1, new_first := i.first_column, on = .(first_column)]
df2[df1, new_first := i.first_column, on = .(second_column = first_column)]
# hget value of new second column
df2[, new_second := ifelse(new_first == first_column, second_column, first_column)]
#       first_column   second_column       new_first      new_second
# 1: ENSG00000142192 ENSG00000165588 ENSG00000165588 ENSG00000142192
# 2: ENSG00000140575 ENSG00000165588 ENSG00000165588 ENSG00000140575
# 3: ENSG00000165588 ENSG00000186908 ENSG00000165588 ENSG00000186908
# 4: ENSG00000165588 ENSG00000135446 ENSG00000165588 ENSG00000135446
# 5: ENSG00000213551 ENSG00000273983 ENSG00000213551 ENSG00000273983
# 6: ENSG00000213551 ENSG00000274267 ENSG00000213551 ENSG00000274267
# 7: ENSG00000197153 ENSG00000213551 ENSG00000213551 ENSG00000197153

# get final answer
df2[, .(first_column = new_first, second_column = new_second)]
#       first_column   second_column
# 1: ENSG00000165588 ENSG00000142192
# 2: ENSG00000165588 ENSG00000140575
# 3: ENSG00000165588 ENSG00000186908
# 4: ENSG00000165588 ENSG00000135446
# 5: ENSG00000213551 ENSG00000273983
# 6: ENSG00000213551 ENSG00000274267
# 7: ENSG00000213551 ENSG00000197153
```

Comment: df2[, new_second := ifelse(new_first == first_column, second_column, first_column)], error after running this code.                                                                                                         Error in Ops.factor(new_first, first_column) : 
  level sets of factors are different

Comment: Can you please help me to solve the error

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error